# Mail attachment using queue in VB

Tags: vb.net, email, stack, queue, attachment

I am attempting to use a queue in my mailing system to send multiple attachments.
The idea is that every time the user attaches a file, the file is saved into a variable and that variable is pushed onto the queue. Multiple attachments would mean a larger queue. I would assume I can attach the queue to the e-mail and send it but when I attempt that I get the error '(68) Value of type 'System.Collections.Queue' cannot be converted to 'System.Net.Mail.Attachment'.' 
How can I fix this? Or is there any alternative way I can send multiple attachments? I absolutely need to make use of either queues or stacks because this is a project for college and it is essential for me to use one of the two. I have included the code that runs after the user clicks the 'send mail' button.

`If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ToMail.Text) OrElse RegexClass.MailRegex(ToMail.Text)) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid email address")
        Else
            Try
                mail.From = New MailAddress(My.Settings.SaveMailID)
                mail.To.Add(ToMail.Text)
                mail.Body = MailBody.Text
                mail.Subject = MailSubject.Text
                mail.Priority = MailPriority.Normal
                Dim smtpserver As New SmtpClient(My.Settings.SMTP, My.Settings.Port)
                smtpserver.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(My.Settings.SaveMailID, My.Settings.SaveMailPass)
                If My.Settings.SMTP = "smtp.gmail.com" And My.Settings.Port = "25" Then
                    smtpserver.EnableSsl = True
                End If
                smtpserver.Port = My.Settings.Port
                smtpserver.Host = My.Settings.SMTP
                If Not Attachbox.Text = Nothing Then
                    Dim attach As New Attachment(Attachbox.Text)
                    mail.Attachments.Add(attach)
                End If
                If Not CCBox.Text = Nothing Then
                    mail.CC.Add(CCBox.Text)
                End If
                If Not BCCBox.Text = Nothing Then
                    mail.Bcc.Add(BCCBox.Text)
                End If
                smtpserver.Send(mail)
                Label7.Show()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End If`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice these key lines:

```
Dim attach As New Attachment(Attachbox.Text)
mail.Attachments.Add(attach)
```

You won't be able to directly attach a Queue because it is not the right type (it is expecting an Attachment object).  However, you can loop over your queue or stack and use these two lines inside the loop to create the attachment and then Add it to your attachments list.

Since this is homework I'm attempting to be somewhat vague but let me know if you have any additional questions.

Here's an MSDN Doc on the attachment class:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.attachments(v=vs.110).aspx

Here's an example of looping over a queue:

```
For Each element As String In queue
    Console.WriteLine(element)
```

You will want to do this and instead of writing to the console, create an Attachment and add it to the Attachment list of your mail object.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by looping over a queue or stack?

Comment: Don't worry about being specific, it is more of a project that I need to include some features in the code and queues/stack is one of them. Thank you!

Comment: I updated the answer with some more info about looping over a queue.  If this answer is helpful please upvote it and choose it as the accepted answer!  If you need any more clarification, please let me know.